# Is there a way to use a variable in your select statement for multiple columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dynamic piece of SQL. It takes about 4 minutes to run. If I instead make it static SQL, it takes about 20 seconds.

Pretty much, the two queries are:

```
@myVar = 1
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE someColumn = myVar
```

vs:

```
@myQuery = '
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE someColumn = myVar'

EXEC sp_executesql @myQuery,
    N'@myVar INT,
    @myVar
```

My real query is much much more complicated. Looking at the statistics, the dynamic one has more than `10x` the number of reads.  I want to make this query static to fix this. The whole reason it's dynamic though is that my insert and select is made using a variable.

I have something like:

```
@someVar1 = "column1, column2, column3"
@someVar2 = "column4, column5, column6"
```

and then will have

```
@myQuery = 'INSERT INTO '+ @someVar1 + 
           'SELECT ' + @someVar2 + ' FROM ....'
```

etc.

Is there any way I could just do something like:

```
INSERT INTO @myVar1
SELECT @myVar2
FROM
...
```

I don't know how else to fix this query, and it desperately needs fixing.

**EDIT** I made some changes. I forgot to mention that the dynamic stuff is also in an insert statement. This is what happens when I make a post after just waking up.

Comment: No, SQL Server won't let you reference columns, tables etc. with variables, you'll need to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: The real way to fix it is to return all the columns in your `SELECT` but change what displays in your application layer instead of generating your `SELECT` on the fly.

Comment: @JNK Can you elaborate?

Comment: @user1652427 why do you need a dynamic `SELECT`?  If you user only wants to see 5 columns from the query, return ALL the columns but only display what they want.  This is basically confusing display code with data code which can cause performance issues.

Comment: Updated the original post. Forgot to mention I also need dynamic columns in the insert.

Comment: Re: the edit, if you need dynamic inserts and selects in this manner then you will need to either redesign so you can use non-dynamic code or basically suck it up and deal with the iffy performance.  Most experienced folks will tell you dynamic SQL for inserts especially is not really recommended, and often it is an indicator of a design problem.

Comment: Maybe you can try this - Select ALL columns into #temp table using static SQL, and then just use dynamic SQL to select results from #temp table?

Comment: I find it hard to believe that a dynamic version of the same query has 10x more reads, unless the query plan behind it got cached with really bad parameters. You might consider including the `RECOMPILE` option on the query, especially if it's unlikely the same query will be executed twice. You might also want to enable `optimize for ad hoc workloads` to prevent single-use plans from filling up the cache.

Comment: Can you show two *actual* queries and their *actual* execution plans that show this difference in reads, where everything else about the queries is the same?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot show the actual queries. I can't really obfuscate it either, it's a MASSIVE statement with Union's of complex nesting of selects.

Answer (score 1):

You are chasing unicorns. SQL Server will not let you replace `@var` with `column1, column2` in a non-dynamic query. The syntax just doesn't support what you would like it to do (not that it would improve the situation anyway).

So you need to solve this "problem" in other ways. I find it extremely difficult to believe that the dynamic version of the same query leads to a 10x displacement in reads. If this is the case (and you aren't just exaggerating for effect - please show evidence), it is almost certainly due to parameter sniffing where the (static) query that is cached used parameters that led to one plan shape, and that plan shape is not optimal for the other (dynamic) query which either has different query text or different parameters or both. You can counteract that to some degree by forcing `RECOMPILE` at runtime and ensuring the query text is identical every time (this includes white space, capitalization, etc.).

```
SET @myQuery = N'INSERT dbo.DestinationTable(' 
  + @DestinationColumns + ')
  SELECT ' + @SourceColumns + '
  FROM dbo.SourceTable
  WHERE someColumn = @myVar OPTION (RECOMPILE);';
```

But I'm not convinced that's your issue, either. I think it may be more perception/fear than actual observation.

As I mentioned in a comment, if you are building a lot of different dynamic SQL statements, you should consider turning on the `optimize for ad hoc workloads` setting, which will prevent your plan cache from getting bloated with plans that you won't ever use again.

The free version of [SQL Sentry Plan Explorer](http://sqlsentry.net/plan-explorer/) will allow you to obfsucate your plans quite easily in about half a second, and even let you upload them where we can look at them. This won't let us dissect the actual query text, but it will show that there are differences in the plan for the query itself - which it doesn't really matter if the query was constructed dynamically or not, just that it is different. *Disclaimer: I work for SQL Sentry.*

Comment: Not an exaggeration. Looking at ~4440000 reads vs ~350000. I've tried both Recompile and optimize for ad hoc workloads. Unfortunately I haven't seen any performance improvements.

Comment: @user1652427 show the actual execution plans, please. I guarantee you there is more difference than just "one is dynamic, one is static."

Comment: The query plans are completely different. There is no difference other than the sp_executesql though, I promise (I've had a few other eyes on this to make sure i'm not crazy)

Comment: @user1652427 well I don't mean to sound crass, but I don't believe you. If the query plans are different, then either the query text is different, the parameters are different, or the plan was flushed after a major stats / data update etc. If you want help investigating this, you're going to have to provide more information. Otherwise, my first paragraph remains: you can't magically fix this because there is no way to do what you think will fix it (which wouldn't fix it even if it were possible).

Comment: My understanding was the optimizer doesn't handle dynamic SQL nearly as well, and will often have different query plans (though my case may be a little more extreme). Is this right, or have I been misinformed?

Comment: @user1652427 I think you may be relying on extremely old information. The reason a plan may be different when executed via dynamic SQL could be as subtle as an extra space between FROM and the table name. But when the query text is identical, the same plan should be used.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27105/discussion-between-user1652427-and-aaron-bertrand)